# how to judge the request is from my computer to the php page?

Tags: php, debugging

How can I determine if the request is from my computer to the php page?

I want to `print_r($GLOABALS)` to debug my site from my computer, but I don't want other computers to do this.

```
<?php
  // can not use ip to judge wheather this computer is mine 
  // for my ip will change always.
  if($is_my_computer){
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this. I would probably go with a cookie. You could also use a query var that only you know to trigger debug mode, eg `index.php?debug=somesupersecretvalue`

Comment: I often set up a subdomain pointing to the same site (when working locally, you can do this with hosts also), and check for the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and start in debug mode if necessary.

Comment: You should be able to restrict it to your IP even if it changes often - I'm assuming you don't want this debug info to be permanent. I do this in large systems where multiple developers and clients all have access but I want to print out debug info that only I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in your local machine you have your website under localhost/mylocalwebsite. If so, just check if you are in this environment and that is it.

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') {
    echo "foo";
  }
```